# MySQL Explain rows limit

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Below is my query to get 20 rows with genre_id 1.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM (`content`) 
WHERE `genre_id` = '1' 
AND `category` = 1
LIMIT 20
```

I have total 654 rows in content table with genre_id 1, I have index on genre_id and in above query I am limiting result to display only 20 records which is working fine but explain is showing 654 records under rows, I tried to add index on category but still same result and then also I removed AND category = 1 but same rows count:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  content ref genre_id    genre_id    4   const   654 Using where
```

[HERE](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/mysql-explain-limits-and-errors/) I found the answer

> LIMIT is not taken into account while estimating number of rows Even
>   if you have LIMIT which restricts how many rows will be examined MySQL
>   will still print full number

But also In comments another reply was posted:

> LIMIT is now taken into account when estimating number of rows. I’m
>   not sure which version addressed this, but in 5.1.30, EXPLAIN
>   accurately takes LIMIT into account.

I am using MySQL 5.5.16 with InnoDB. so as per above comment its still not taking into account. So my question is does mysql go through all 654 rows to return 20 rows even I have set limit? Thanks

Comment: I _believe_ this means that while you may limit the number of rows displayed, it is possible that the database engine may have to look at more rows than you see. Not sure is good example, but, for instance, when you do order by and select top 10 rows, the db engine still has to process the entire table to do the order.

Comment: Thanks but I am not using order by, I even removed AND condition from above code but it still display total count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reply from [Rick James](http://forums.mysql.com/profile.php?24,31192) at [MySQL](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,597352,597431#msg-597431)

> Does mysql LIMIT is taken into account when estimating number of rows in Explain?
>
> No. (5.7 with JSON may be a different matter.)