# Is there any way to prevent MySQL from reading entire table when I specify to select first 10 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in MYSQL `Table1` database that contains 2 million records, I would make an appointment and to return only the first 10 records;

Then the next thought: `SELECT FROM table1 LIMIT 10;`, which returns only the 10 records.

When I run `EXPLAIN SELECT from table1 LIMIT 10;` reports that come across the table, or 2 million records to return only 10.

How to prevent a SQL query (MYSQL) read off the entire table?

Comment: If you have such a simple query (e.g. no `order by` or `group by` or perhaps some other constructs), then MySQL will return the first ten records it encounters and never get around to reading the rest of the records.

Answer (score 3):

EXPLAIN does not respect the LIMIT clause while estimating the number of rows. Please find more details here: [MySQL Explain rows limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334640/mysql-explain-rows-limit)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have grouping or sorting operations, the SQL engine will return rows in the order that it finds them, and so `LIMIT 10` will cause it to not bother looking after the first 10.

If appropriately indexed, this applies for ordered (and probably grouped) queries as well -- the engine can look up the top value, get that row, look up the next best, get that one, and so on... until it hits the row limit and stops.

If you're curious, compare the execution speed of with/without `LIMIT` (just make sure to discard the results), as well as with/without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I'm already using the "LIMIT" but in "EXPLAIN" command reports that pecorreu entire table.